# How to load image while the full content loads in webpage

Tags: javascript, iis-6

Hi i have webpage taking too long to load due to acsx controls and DB calls. before loading the content , page took 3-4 secs leaving blank screen for users. So what is the best way , so that i can load a loading gif when it is taking 3-4 secs to get content from server. So that there will be no blank white page when user go to page

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884194/pre-compress-static-files-in-iis-6

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a minifyer to compress your javascript? Like [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) one. Also Jeff Atwood wrote a blog post about HTTP compression and IIS6 you can read [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html).

Comment: Hi i have webpage taking too long to load due to acsx controls and DB calls. before loading the content , page took 3-4 secs leaving blank screen for users. So what is the best way , so that i can load a loading gif when it is taking 3-4 secs to get content from server. So that there will be no blank white page when user go to page.

Comment: Are you using ajax for these calls?

Comment: no i am using simple .net controls to get the content. Everything is good , there is only blank screen for first 3-4 secs , which i want to replace with some animation or image so that when i hit the link there is something on screen for user while the page is loading

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a GZIP:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jun/29/HttpWebRequest-and-GZip-Http-Responses